# Locally Hosted Google App Engine (WebApp Framework / BigTable)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mod-wsgi

I have been playing with Google App engine a lot lately, from home on personal projects, and I have been really enjoying it. I've converted a few of my coworkers over and we are interested in using GAE for a few of our projects at work.

Our work has to be hosted locally on our own servers. I've done some searching around and I really can't find any information on using the WebApp framework and BigTable locally.

Any information you could provide on setting up a GAE-ish environment on a local Windows server would be much appreciated. I know GAE is much more than just the framework and BigTable - the scalability, propogation of your application/data across many servers are all features we **don't** need. We just want to get the webapp framework and BigTable up and running through mod_wsgi on Apache.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892411/breaking-out-of-the-google-app-engine-python-lock-in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webapp is a fine choice for a simple web framework but there are plenty of other simple python web frameworks that have instructions for setting them up in your use case (cherrypy, web.py, etc). Since google developed webapp for gae I don't believe they published instructions for setting it up behind apache.

BigTable is proprietary to Google so you will not be able to run it locally. If you are looking for something with similar performance characteristics I'd look into the schemaless 'document-oriented' databases.